# How does one serialize an XDocument object?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

I want to serialize an `XDocument` object. I wrote this code.

```
        XDocument signup_xml_file = new XDocument(
            new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
            new XComment("signup_xml_file"),
            new XElement("Student",
                new XElement("univ_id", univ_id),
                new XElement("personal_id",personal_id),
                new XElement("user_name", user_name)));
        client.Connect(host_name, port);
        //connect to the server .
        bf.Serialize(client.GetStream(), signup_xml_file); // serialize the signup_xml_file
```

I get the following exception when attempting to serialize the `XDocument`.  Is there any way to make the `XDocument` class Serializable, or is there another way to send my `XDocument`?

> Type 'System.Xml.Linq.XDocument' in Assembly 'System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is not marked as serializable.

Answer (score 10):

XDocuments are not intended to be serialized. In a way they are serializers themselves.

But you can simply write them: `signup_xml_file.Save(client.GetStream());`
which also eliminates serializer overhead.

Edit:

And on the other side you will need

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(someStream);
```

Comment: the problem in saving the xml file that :
1- the client have to save the xml file in it's harddisck
2- when the server recieved the file it has to save it in the server dick then load the file from the Xdocument.load("path") 
3- delete the file from the server

Comment: No, the other side can just as easily load it from the Stream. See Edit. There will be no need for a file where the Serializer doesn't need one.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any reason why you'd want to serialize the `XDocument` object. Just serialize the XML string that you can get by calling `ToString()` on the document.

And I don't see any reason to use binary serialization here at all. If you actually don't need it, you can just write the XML string to the output.

Comment: i want to send the data in a xml document to server so i must serializing it to send ?? where is the wrong ??

Comment: can you explaining more what you mean ??

Comment: You don't want to send the `XDocument` object, serialized using binary serialization. You want to send the actual XML document, as a string. To do that, you have to get the string from the `XDocument`.

Comment: Using `ToString` is fine for small XML documents, but if you're working with large XML documents then it's better to work with streams to avoid allocating huge chunks of memory for only a few moments. Streams keep everything running smoothly by reducing GC pressure. [My answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12723266/24874) shows what I mean.

Comment: A good reason to serialise an XDocument is to encrypt the contents in one go.  So this is plausible.  In which case use the XmlTextWriter to write to a string.  Then encrypt the string.

Answer (score 2):

If you want more control over serialisation of `XDocument`, use the `WriteTo` function and create your own `XmlWriter`.

Here's an example:

```
using (new XmlTextWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8) { Formatting = Formatting })
    _document.WriteTo(xmlTextWriter);
```